# How to optimize SQL/Python select queries against a db2 database?

Tags: python, sql, db2

Connected via Python to a db2 database on server and querying against an enormous table (perhaps 200-mil records, 50-cols). This table is for analytics (OLAP might be the correct term) rather than transactions. I would like to optimize my sql/python code for faster query execution.

Without a deep understanding of sql queries, my suspicion is that `SELECT` statements begin at the first record of the table and continue until the query is satisfied. `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` executes in <1 second. However, including `WHERE date_col > 20210701` would need to scan through a couple 100-mil records before identifying the first 10 records--a query that takes more than a few minutes to execute. Performance is similar via the cursor object.

Alternatively, I am connected to the same table through Microsoft Access. The same date query in Access executes in <.5 seconds--even faster than my fastest `SELECT` statement. Surely Access is doing something behind the scenes that I don't know about.

So Access proves the concept that these sql queries **can** be executed quickly. I am left with the question: How can I optimize my sql/python code to match the performance of Microsoft Access? Thanks all.

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db
import pandas as pd 

cnxn = db.connect(dsn=     '********', 
                  user=    '********', 
                  password='********', 
                  host=    '********', 
                  database='********')   

cols = "{0}col1, {0}col2, {0}col3, {0}col4".format('database.')

# Executes in <1 second
fast_sql = '''SELECT {} FROM bigtable
              FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY'''.format(cols)

# Executes in ~5 seconds 
slower_sql = '''SELECT {} FROM bigtable
                WHERE col1 = 1234
                FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY'''.format(cols)

# Giving up after ~3 minutes
slowest_sql = '''SELECT {} FROM bigtable 
                       WHERE date_col > 20210701
                       FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY'''.format(cols) 

df = pd.read_sql_query(horribly_slow_sql , cnxn)

cnxn.close()
```

Comment: You'd need to see what queries are actually being sent to the database server in each case. Also, how do you measure execution time?

Comment: Any indexes? Any information on the table design? What type is date_col? Start with some performance basics, i.e., by collecting facts in a reproducible environment.

Comment: By "mil" do you mean millions or thousands?

Comment: @mustaccio how would I find the actual sql sent to the database from Microsoft Access? Google is no help so far. Any ideas?

Comment: @data_henrik appreciate the response. Exploring the "Object Definition" properties through access suggests that there are 7 indices. They are a bit cryptic though, so I'm not sure how they're actually being passed into Access' sql query. This is a good jumping-off point though.

Comment: @TheImpaler million, not thousand.

Comment: [snapshot information from the dynsql logical data group](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-snap-get-dyn-sql-dynsql-snapshot).

Comment: @data_henrik a bit more information. The 7 indexes cover all relevant fields. I have learned that these indexes do not need to be called explicitly, but should optimize the query "automagically". I have also found that the data type of the date_col is CHAR. However, both of these facts should be compatible with basic `SELECT * FROM bigtbl WHERE date_col > 20210701`. I'm still not sure why my queries are taking so long via Python but are lightning-fast in Access. Anything else you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple factors influenced the issue.

1. Foremost was a simple datatype issue. The date_col was not an integer nor a datetime, but rather a CHAR format. This was causing an indexing issue, resulting in slow queries. Problem resolved by putting the result in quotes: `...WHERE date_col > '20210701'` rather than `...WHERE date_col > 20210701`.
2. The other issue was a misunderstanding with how Access processes data. When toggling to "Datasheet view", Access does not execute the whole query. Rather, it performs an operation equivalent to `FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY`. The query appeared so fast because the server did not need to send the entire dataset to the client. However, the entire query executes when exporting. In my case, this takes roughly 5 seconds and represents a process equivalent to the Python script I'm performing.

Thank you all for the comments above.